# How cheap are http requests?

Tags: sockets, http, webserver, httprequest

For my current project I need communication through a server. The communication works in transmission of very small packets every 20-30 seconds. Sometimes, the server will need to send something back. Right now, I'm torn between the option of setting up a http webserver and let the server functionality run in PHP, handling the request like an update and request at once, or set up an "actual server" that has a more or less steady connection to the client, thus enabling the client to send packets without much overhead, and the server to answer whenever it needs.

It would be easier to implement the http webserver solution for me, though. Thus my question... How "cheap" are http requests? Can I omit the user agent to only send my small packets and wait for a small answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheap is relative and if HTTP is cheap enough for your use case depends on your requirements. If you have ample and cheap bandwidth with normal latency then HTTP is cheap. If you have only very small bandwidth on an expensive and high latency satellite link then the overhead of HTTP can be really expensive, both in money and latency.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to specify - By cheap I simply meant the "amount of data" I would have as overhead. (How many bytes of overhead I'll have, basically.). Obviously, one "overhead" I'll have to include is the IP Address - But I'd like to avoid everything else if possible. (The data I need to send a few times every minute will be sent from mobile phones, over data (3G, H, 4G, LTE, you get it)(Sorry for the use of wrong terms) and not wifi. Which is why I need to use as few bytes as possible.

Comment: I'm also asking because, due to the "briefness" of the data exchange, I don't need any persisting connection - And I would want to avoid handshake packets anyway. In other words, I'm considering using a simple http webserver as server in case I can avoid as much overhead as possible.

Comment: @user2065501: in this case you don't want to use HTTP but simply TCP or even UDP (depending on how reliable it should be).

Comment: Okay then. The problem is that I don't have a deep knowledge on this matter. How would I go about establishing a non-persistent connection? I've done "persistent" connections before, by sending handshakes etc, but would not sending those suffice? I'm sorry. It's been a long time, haha.

Comment: @user2065501: this is a different question than the original one and thus does not belong in a comment but should be asked as a new question.

Comment: Right, I will, sorry.